# Import Keywords section in robot script

Tags: robotframework, keyword

I am working with robot framework and want to know if it is possible to save my Keywords that I build in section ***Keyword*** and import them in other robot scripts?

I hope you understand my question and can give me some helps.

Best
Pouyan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the purpose of a Resource file. You can move that **Keywords** section to a file with extension .robot or .resource, and then in the test suite file at **Settings** section use the `Resource    your_resource.resource` import.

A resource file cannot have test cases.